# Swagger Logout button does not clear user session from browser ( Azure B2C in ASP.Net 6 web api)

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, swagger, azure-ad-b2c, swagger-ui

I Implemented Authentication and authorization on ASP.net 6 with Azure B2C,and everything works fine except the Logout button on the authorization modal provided by Swagger, as it  appears to log the user out, but after "logging out" the user can click "Authorize" and be logged in again without being required to enter their username and password. It's not clearing out the user session from the browser. On the client side developed in vueJs , the logout works fine , the issue is happening only with swagger, I tried to track the flow of the HTTP requests and it appears that clicking the logout button does not trigger any http calls in order to logout the user or clear his session.
Am using the nuget package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.3.0 , any suggestions ?Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clearing Cookies session during logout button having issues in ASP .NET Core and still it is in open state on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7203) Repo.

Same it is not possible to do external logout using [OAuth](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7707)

Please keep trace of this issue in the GitHub. Also, if possible, contact the technical support of Microsoft Azure on `azcommunity@microsoft.com`